# Margins in a div aren't working properly

Tags: html, css

I'm making some experiments with a simple fluid grid only with a sidebar and a main area. When I try to put some margins in an div inside the main area, the margin doesn't work properly, but in the sidebar it works fine. Here is the Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/swayziak/vVJeV/

HTML:

```
<section class="sidebar">
    <div class="test"> bla bla bla bla bla ba balalalalal </div>
</section>

<section class="mainarea">
    <div class="test"> bla bla bla bla bla ba balalalalal </div>
 </section>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar {
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 100;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 25%;
   height: 100%;
   border-right: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
   background: #FFF;
 }

.mainarea {     
   float: right;
   z-index: 100;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 75%;
   height: 100%;
 }

.test {    
   margin-left: 24px;
 }
```

Probably the problem is related with some part of the .sidebar and .mainarea CSS, but I don't know which one.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean the margin doesn't work properly? I see a left margin on both the sidebar and main area working fine. Can you clarify?

Comment: The margin of the div test inside the mainarea isn't working properly. I put a margin of 24px, but the browser shows a margin with a different size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your answer..  **[Example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/vVJeV/2/)**

Your problem was that the sidebar was taking up 25%, and the mainarea was 75%.. This would normally work, however, you had a `border-right` of 1 px.. Therefore the total adds up to 101%..

These are the changes I made:

```
.sidebar {
    float:left; /* Added this in */
    width:24%; /* Changed to 25 to 24 */
}
```

Let me know if you need anymore help, or if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still doesn't work. The margin in the div inside the sidebar is correct (24px), but the div in the mainarea is assuming a margin of (32px).

Comment: where are you testing this? I'm looking at it on chrome and it works fine. 24px left margin.

Comment: @user2473588 Have you tried something lower? Such as 20%? 24% seems to work in my browser (chrome), along with other people using chrome too.

Comment: @rgin Thanks for the information! Glad it works in chrome, just need to figure this out for other browsers now..

Comment: I'm using Chrome and it doesn't work: http://imgur.com/2wH1qCS The margin of the div in the main area assumes 32px

Comment: It's not that. Why I put a margin-left of 24px in the div, but in the div inside the mainarea the margin-left that appears is 8px: http://imgur.com/63YMppD

Comment: I added in a CSS Reset, is this what you were aiming for? http://jsfiddle.net/vVJeV/7/

Comment: Thanks, I think that now it works. Which part of the CSS reset is related with this problem?